# Copy a row between 2 jquery Datatables and then update my DB

Tags: jquery-ui, datatables, drag-and-drop

I already have a portion of this working using Jquery-Ui, I'd appreciate some further input.

I am able to drag and drop a row from Table1 onto Table2.

*issues*

When I drop the new row, it does appear on table2 but table2 collapses for some reason and I have to expand it to see the new row
Table1 looks like the row was removed but if you use the Order arrow it reappears. - ***This issue has been fixed***

Additional Question...
I wish to push this new row of data into my db via ajax call...should I try to send the data at the end of the table2.droppable function or should I use some datatbles function in table2 to realise there is new data and then fire?

```
    <table class="dataTable" id="table1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Rendering engine</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Trident</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Trident</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Trident</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Trident</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>

    <h2>Table 2</h2>
    <table class="dataTable" id="table2">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Rendering engine</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

    </table>

            var t1 = $('#table1').DataTable();
            var t2 = $('#table2').DataTable();

            //this will hold reference to the tr we have dragged and its helper
            var c = {};

            $("#table1 tr").draggable({
                helper: "clone",
                start: function (event, ui) {
                    c.tr = this;
                    c.helper = ui.helper;
                }
            });


            $("#table2").droppable({
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    t2.row.add(c.tr).draw();

                    // <-- Do this if you want to remove the rows from the first table
                    $(c.tr).remove();
                    $(c.helper).remove();

                    //Redraw Table1
                    t1.draw();
                    // -->
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rj1f6896/)

Comment: "When I drop the new row, it does appear on table2 but table2 collapses for some reason and I have to expand it to see the new row Table1 looks like the row was removed but if you use the Order arrow it reappears."... add `t2.draw();` after `t1.draw();`

Comment: @S.Walker You're correct, that did fix that issue - thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the code as follows. This will allow you to handle any exceptions that may occur in the process of inserting data in the database.

```js
            

            var t1 = $('#table1').DataTable();
            var t2 = $('#table2').DataTable();

            //this will hold reference to the tr we have dragged and its helper
            var c = {};

            $("#table1 tr").draggable({
                helper: "clone",
                start: function (event, ui) {
                    c.tr = this;
                    c.helper = ui.helper;
                }
            });


            $("#table2").droppable({
                drop: function (event, ui) {                   
                    
                    
                    //Insert the data into my database.
                    insertData(function (success) {
                     if (success) {
                           //Move the row.
                            t2.row.add(c.tr).draw();
                            $(c.tr).remove();
                           $(c.helper).remove();
                        
                            //Re-draw the tables.
                            t1.draw();
                      t2.draw();
                      }
                      else {
                           //Handle a failed insert.
                            alert("Unable to insert data!");
                      }        
                    });
                    
                    
                }
            });
            
            function insertData(cb) {
             //Perform some AJAX.
              
              //Test a success.
              cb(true);
              
              //Test a Failure.
              //cb(false);
              
            }
```

Comment: Argh, I'm just realizing that the jquery-ui doesnt seem to work with data that is ajax'd in,

Comment: I ended up going in another direction due to the jquery-ui issue, i instead used a cell selector click on each table to overwrite the contents but I did use some of your example.
https://jsfiddle.net/hqjtgmec/